# "Thread-1" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: multithreading, exception, runnable

My code is:

```
 public class Application {
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{
    Fifo f = new Fifo();

    Producer pr = new Producer("elso",f);

    pr.go();


    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Consumer cr = new Consumer("csacsi",f,1000);
    cr.start();
}
 } 

 public class Producer extends Thread{

String szoveg;
int szam;
Fifo ff;

Producer(String s, Fifo f){ ff = f; szoveg =s; szam = 0; }

public void go(){
        start();
}

public void run(){
    while(szam<6)
    try {
        sleep(1000);

        ff.put(szoveg+ " "+szam);
        System.out.println("producer" +" " +ff.get()+" "+System.currentTimeMillis()%100000);
        //System.out.println(szoveg +" "+ szam+ "     "+System.currentTimeMillis()%100000);
        szam++;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("fasz");
    }

    //szam+=1;
}
 }

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class Fifo {

ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();


 synchronized void put(String s) throws InterruptedException{
    while(str.size()>9){

        //Thread.sleep(10); 
    }
    str.add(s);
}

String get() throws InterruptedException{
    synchronized(str){
     if(str.size()==0) str.wait();
     if(str.size()!=0) str.notifyAll();
         //Thread.sleep(10);
     String s = str.get(0);
     str.remove(0);
     return s;}
 }
 }


 public class Consumer extends Thread{
Fifo F;
String S;
int I,asd;

Consumer (String s, Fifo f, int i){
    F=f; S=s; I=i;
}

public void run(){
    while(asd<6){
        try {
            sleep(I);
            System.out.println("consumer "+F.get());
            asd++;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
 }
```

and the outputs:

```
producer elso 0 34491
producer elso 1 35493
producer elso 2 36493Exception in thread "Thread-1" 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at alap.Fifo.get(Fifo.java:24)
at alap.Consumer.run(Consumer.java:16)
producer elso 3 37495
producer elso 4 38496
producer elso 5 39496
```

So, what is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `synchronized`, you need to synchronize on the exact same instance in both threads that should be protected from each other, otherwise it won't have the desired effect.

Your `put` method is synchronizing on `this`, whereas your `get` method is synchronizing on `str`, and those are two different objects, so it doesn't have the necessary protective effect.

Comment: can u show me, how synchronize on the exact same instance in both threads?

Comment: You just need to write the synchronized in the same way in both cases. So change `String get() throws InterruptedException` to `synchronized String get() throws InterruptedException`, and delete the `synchronized (str){` and the matching `}` inside it.

Comment: Well I thought that is what you refer to. This has already been tried.   output: Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
 at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
 at alap.Fifo.get(Fifo.java:23)
 at alap.Producer.run(Producer.java:22)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
 at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
 at alap.Fifo.get(Fifo.java:23)
 at alap.Consumer.run(Consumer.java:16)

Comment: right, so you _also_ need to call `wait` and `notifyAll` on the exact same instance, i.e. `this`.

Comment: Yes, but there is still fault somewhere. you can see the outputs.

Comment: @Farkangyal So change your code to what they are suggesting. Then change your example to the new code. Then tell us what error you are getting.